# Use host networking while building a VSCode devcontainer

Tags: docker, vscode-remote

How can I get VSCode to use host networking during the build of the container?
In devcontainer.json, I can set

```
"runArgs": ["--network=host"]
```

but that only applies to running the container.  How can I get VSCode to use host networking during the build of the container?

Answer (score 4):

As of now, proper solution does not exist, correspondent PR is open:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/3545

A workaround mentioned in this PR is using `initializeCommand` in combination with `image`:

```
 "initializeCommand": "docker build --network host --tag my-image .",
  "image": "my-image"
```

Answer (score 2):

## UPDATE 2023

The solution below no longer works. According to a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/4272#issuecomment-772665186) you can use this instead:

```
"runArgs": [
    "--network=host",
],
```

## Original Solution (no longer works)

You need to add the following in your devcontainer.json file:

```
    "build": {
        "args": {
            "network": "host"
        }
    }
```

This property will allow you to use the host network when building.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore, it adds `--build-arg network=host` instead of `--network=host`

Comment: Sorry for downvoting, but it does not work anymore as stated by @madhur4127
I try to provide the answer below.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I have updated the answer to include a working solution.

Comment: @Oren_C As far as I understood, `runArgs` are only for running, and the question is about building

Answer (score 1):

I have met a similar problem that I want to use host proxy configuration to build.

I add this in devcontainer.json:

```
    "build": {
        "args": {
            "HTTP_PROXY": "your_proxy_ip:port",
        }
    }
```

For other config, you could do the same.

Hope it will be helpful to you.

see more details here:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg